# Выключение телефона

Tags: mobile, android, java

Привет всем. Есть потребность учесть в интерфейсе приложения выключения телефона.

Не подскажите, где бы можно было прочитать про метод или какая вообще информация есть на этот счет?

Comment: Непонятно. Вы собираетесь программно выключать телефон из вашей проги или при выключении телефона что-то делать? Уточните вопрос!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если речь идет о том, чтобы программно выключить/перезагрузить телефон:

1. то это требует разрешения [REBOOT](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#REBOOT) в манифесте.
2. приложение должно быть подписано ключом системной прошивки

При наличии такого разрешения можно отправить телефон на перезагрузку (не выключить!) через `PowerManager.reboot()`

**Update**

на рутованном аппарате можно попробовать выполнить

```
Runtime.getRuntime().exec("su reboot");
```

может поможет - не знаю не пробовал.

Comment: Где взять ключ системной прошивки?

Comment: Ключи у поставщика прошивки... У открытых прошивок (типа Cyanogen) они есть и находятся где-то в недрах исходников

Comment: Есть реализация подобной функции? Т.к. это приложение будет размещено в Play Google. А получается, у каждого тлф своя прошивка и свой ключ системной прошивки, получается нужно его как-то вытягивать

Comment: Может проще через $su reboot? - на рутованном аппарате должно сработать...

Comment: почитай дискуссию с программным reboot'ом здесь http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/5a97467ef5b4bf47/a1fe9379d4f5e30f

Comment: @V_Tjuryakin, зачем такие вещи вообще задумывать ? 

Кому-нибудь вкдь может **реально** не понравиться, что *фиг его знает какая прилада так о себе возомнила*.

Что делать будете ?

Comment: @Barmaley, т.е. я так понимаю у тех устройств у которых нету root - работать не будет? Или для этого тоже есть какой-то обход?

Comment: @avp, это действие дистанционно будет производить хозяин устройства. Так-что я думаю, его все устроит :) Отключение будет по системе:
Он на пк нажал - C2DM - устройство.

Comment: @V_Tjuryakin я думаю, что обхода нет - тут без вариантов